# content is scrolling behind div it is meant to be inside of

Tags: html, css

I have a div, content has been placed in the div. However, the content is overflowing out of the div, and oddly scrolling behind the div. Which is stopping the actual page from scrolling.

could someone help me to detect why this is happening.

All the code is being printed out from a db.
This is what is currently happening. The text outside the black and white is the content that is overflowing.

[image]

```css
.option-content {
  /*    background-color: #fff;*/
  /*    overflow:hidden; keep products in div*/
  overflow: auto;
  float: left;
  color: #000;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 200px;
  height: auto !important;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-top: -100px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  border-top: 0 !important;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div id="option-content' . $i . '" class="option-content">
  <table id="ord_details" width="100%">
    <tr id="snd_r1">

      <td>
        <p id="prods' . $i . '" class="prods">' . $Products . '</p>
      </td>
      <td>£ &nbsp; ' . $prod_pric . '</td>

      <hr>
      </br>
    </tr>


  </table>
</div>
```

**New code**

```css
.option-content {
  /*    background-color: #fff;*/
  /*    overflow:hidden; keep products in div*/
  overflow: auto;
  float: left;
  color: #000;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 200px;
  height: auto !important;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-top: -100px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  border-top: 0 !important;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div id="option-content' . $i . '" class="option-content">
  <table id="ord_details" width="100%">
    <tr id="snd_r1">

      <td>
        <p id="prods' . $i . '" class="prods">' . $Products . '</p>
      </td>
      <td>£ &nbsp; ' . $prod_pric . '</td>

    </tr>


  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Your `table` element contains `hr` and `br` in an invalid way, and that will most likely create unexpected result. Post a minimal working code snippet, with those parts cleared, so we have with what to work.

Comment: @LGSon i have removed the hr and br tags no difference

Comment: post a fiddle with an example, is easier to help you that way

Comment: Is there any reason you have `!important`?

Comment: You need to post a working code snippet that reproduces the issue showed in your image. The now posted code is just a fragment of that and miss important parts of the code for us to be able to provide you with a proper answer

Answer (score 0):

```css
.option-content {
  overflow: auto;
  float: left;
  color: #000;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 200px;
  height: auto !important;
  background-color: #fff;
  /*margin-top: -100px;*/
  padding-top: 10px;
  /*border-top: 0 !important;*/
  z-index: -1;

  /* for debugging */
  border: 1px solid red;
  max-height: 240px;
}
```

```html
<div id="option-content1" class="option-content">
  <table id="ord_details" width="100%">
    <tr id="snd_r1">
      <td>
        <p id="prods1" class="prods">awesome product</p>
      </td>
      <td>£ &nbsp; 3.99</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="snd_r1">
      <td>
        <p id="prods1" class="prods">awesome product</p>
      </td>
      <td>£ &nbsp; 3.99</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="snd_r1">
      <td>
        <p id="prods1" class="prods">awesome product</p>
      </td>
      <td>£ &nbsp; 3.99</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="snd_r1">
      <td>
        <p id="prods1" class="prods">awesome product</p>
      </td>
      <td>£ &nbsp; 3.99</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="snd_r1">
      <td>
        <p id="prods1" class="prods">awesome product</p>
      </td>
      <td>£ &nbsp; 3.99</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="snd_r1">
      <td>
        <p id="prods1" class="prods">awesome product</p>
      </td>
      <td>£ &nbsp; 3.99</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="snd_r1">
      <td>
        <p id="prods1" class="prods">awesome product</p>
      </td>
      <td>£ &nbsp; 3.99</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="snd_r1">
      <td>
        <p id="prods1" class="prods">awesome product</p>
      </td>
      <td>£ &nbsp; 3.99</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="snd_r1">
      <td>
        <p id="prods1" class="prods">awesome product</p>
      </td>
      <td>£ &nbsp; 3.99</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="snd_r1">
      <td>
        <p id="prods1" class="prods">awesome product</p>
      </td>
      <td>£ &nbsp; 3.99</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="snd_r1">
      <td>
        <p id="prods1" class="prods">awesome product</p>
      </td>
      <td>£ &nbsp; 3.99</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="snd_r1">
      <td>
        <p id="prods1" class="prods">awesome product</p>
      </td>
      <td>£ &nbsp; 3.99</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="snd_r1">
      <td>
        <p id="prods1" class="prods">awesome product</p>
      </td>
      <td>£ &nbsp; 3.99</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="snd_r1">
      <td>
        <p id="prods1" class="prods">awesome product</p>
      </td>
      <td>£ &nbsp; 3.99</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="snd_r1">
      <td>
        <p id="prods1" class="prods">awesome product</p>
      </td>
      <td>£ &nbsp; 3.99</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

at the moment - the content of div.option-content isn't tall enough to overflow the div.option-content. so i added some more lines. after that i added a max-height value to your div.option-content and et voila the content is scrollable.

Btw, please remove variables in your code with some dummy content. Stackoverflow does not know what '$Products' in your code means.

if you have further questions please feel free to ask.